# R changing Excel Date columns Datatype to Logical during read_excel() if Date column is empty in excel

Tags: r, excel, readr, readxl

So I have 2 excels VIN1.xlsx and VIN2.xlsx that I need to compare.

VIN1 excel has a dale column OUTGATE_DT which is populated for atleast 1 rows.

VIN2 excel has a date column OUTGATE_DT which is completely null for all rows.

when I import VIN1.xlsx excel using read_excel, it creates the object, and when I check the OUTGATE_DT column, it says its datatype to be as POSIXct[1:4] (which I assume is correct for Date Column. )

But when I import VIN2.xlsx excel using read_excel, it creates the object, and when I check the OUTGATE_DT column, it says its datatype to be logical[1:4] (it is doing this because this column is entirely empty).

and that is why my `compare_df(vin1,vin2)` functions failing
stating -

> Error in rbindlist(l, use.names, fill, idcol) :
> Class attribute on column 80 of item 2 does not match with column 80 of item 1.

I am completely new with R, your help would be highly appreciated. TIA

Please check the screenshot for reference.

[image]

Comment: Is the Python tag useful here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, if you want to keep the column types in your original df, you can do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)

VIN2 <- read_excel(VIN2.xlsx) %>%
 mutate(OUTGATE_DT = as.Date(OUTGATE_DT))
```

then you shouldn't have a problem using `rbind` or `bind_rows` from `dplyr`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use read_excel() as the following read_excel(, col_types = "text")

All your columns will be considered as text so you won't have any issue to compare or anything.

Comment: But when I do this.. it stores Dates that are present in diff format.

Comment: example- If date in excel is - 09/25/2020 then it stores it as some numeric value like - 47479.434

Comment: It's normal since it's converting a date format to text. So if you have a column named "Date" in your dataframe, you can do my_df$Date <- convertToDate(my_df$Date) and then my_df$Date <- format(as.Date(my_df$Date), "%d/%m/%Y")